# How hard would it be to create a customisable GUI for mac?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

What I mean by this is, how much work would be involved in rewriting/extending default AppKit controls in a way that would allow for both a standard OS X appearance and custom appearance (loaded from image files) if the user so wishes? (Think of WinAmp or Windows Media Player.) Has anyone tried to bring this to the Mac?

I understand how to redraw an `NSWindow` or a button cell but that's all hard coded. I want something the user can add to themselves. What are my options?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a target audience for this? I remember this CD burner software with the smoke coming out of it and all this fancy UI stuff, but in the end no one really cared about it

Comment: If there's a market for it isn't a factor. I'm giving users the option. Im just not sure how to implement controls that can have there appearance changed via a file at runtime

Comment: Well, you are going to face a lot of work for this, so you should be sure that you don't make it and no one is going to use it (unless you have client that pays enough money per hour)

Comment: It's a personal project but I don't see why the end user shouldn't have these options avalable. Look at ios there's a whole api for changing appearance

Comment: @Jamesp1989 I think it's just unclear what you mean by letting the user change the appearance. Do you mean to give the users options between predefined themes (like light/sepia/dark modes in iBooks), or letting them totally redefine your interface with their own themes?

Comment: I mean allowing the user to create their own ;) if they want to. Kinda like windows media player or Winamp

Comment: Have a look at [`BGHUDAppKit`](https://github.com/binarygod/BGHUDAppKit), it's recently been abandoned but the code is all there.

Comment: @Jamesp1989 Then I'd highly recommend against it. Depending on the project you're working on, it could mean a _lot_ of work for very little benefit. Letting users craft their own user interfaces is likely going to end up as a train wreck of broken UI and confused users. Of course, you're free to do what you want, and as Rob said, `BGHUDAppKit` will provide you with a lot of the information you need, but I think the app you're trying to build is going to end up very un-Mac-like. It's a fun exercise in programming, but not great in a finished product...

Comment: @Jamesp1989 By the way, if I've answered your question sufficiently well, please consider marking it as the correct answer (using the green check mark).

Comment: BGHUDAppKit is broken. The framework compiles just fine but the demo app won't build.

Comment: Would I be better off extending NSControl and creating a base class that can be themed like NSThemeControl then extending it to create my buttons etc?

Comment: @Jamesp1989 No, just subclass the most specific classes you can because they already contain most of the behavior you want. Otherwise, you'll just end up reimplementing a lot of code. So `NSButton` and `NSButtonCell` for buttons, `NSTextField` and `NSTextFieldCell` for text fields, etc.

Comment: @Jamesp1989 There's a general document about subclassing `NSControl` objects [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000730), but don't subclass `NSControl` itself to get the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it would really involved redrawing all the custom components you'd need from scratch, whether in code, or using images. AppKit wasn't meant to be customized as it strictly follows Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html); Apple wants to create one consistent UI metaphor across all native applications.

What that means in practice is that you're going to have to do a lot of custom drawing to theme your app. Using images makes things easier, but not by too much. If you want a custom button, you'll have to create a subclass of `NSButton` and `NSButtonCell` to load the images you want and draw (take a look at `NSDrawThreePartImage()` and `NSDrawNinePartImage()` for how to more easily draw resizable buttons). To theme `NSWindow`, you'll have to subclass `NSThemeFrame`, a semi-private class that draws the standard OS X window look.

Essentially, you'll just need to do a lot of subclassing to get the appearance you want. Is it possible? Absolutely. Is it recommended or easy to do? Not so much.

---

Of course, you have to ask if this is really necessary. The point of the HIG is to try to create one standard look across OS X. If not done expertly, a themed look can be tacky, and possibly even confusing for users who are used to the default OS X look. If you want to include UI theming, there usually needs to be a good reason for it (either to maintain cross-platform compatibility, but in that case, all HIG rules are out the window; or to achieve a specific look, a là game UI), but I really wouldn't recommend doing it, let alone letting users customize your UI themselves.

Comment: `NSThemeFrame` isn't "semi private" but totally private. Or did I miss anything in the latest AppKit releases?

Comment: Also isn't theme frame not needed if you make transparent and do custom drawing? Not tO mention apple are breaking their own HIG with the new theming on the address book and garage band

Comment: @JustSid I say "semi-private" because even though the class itself is private, subclassing it isn't frowned upon by Apple. There are several applications in the Mac App Store (iA Writer, for instance), that override the default look without a hitch.

Comment: @Jamesp1989 You don't _necessarily_ need it, but if you're trying to draw a traditional window with simply a different color scheme, for instance (again, like iA Writer), it's much easier to just subclass it because you play around with laying out the window's close buttons and all that — it's much easier to do it that way.

Comment: Is it worth me getting in contact with a company that has already done what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Jamesp1989 Well, it's really up to your judgement. You mentioned this is a personal project, so it would really depend on the level of commitment (in terms of both time and money) you're willing to make. Again, I don't really think it's a great idea, but if you're committed to it, then go for it and give it your best. If you think it's worth the money, then sure, of course.

Comment: It's a personal project but if the default appearance is aqua I don't see why users shouldnt have the option of an alternate

Comment: @Jamesp1989 Then go for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this fully possible. But are you shure that you want to do this using AppKit? Maybe better use crossplatform solution like QT that support skinning through CSS?

Comment: I have heard bad things about qt in the past. Besides CSS would mean using web kit doesn't it?